# How to put the Steam connection in a NestJS server?

Tags: ionic-framework, nestjs, openid, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I would like to set up a Steam connection in my Ionic/Angular application with NestJS Server.
I can't find anything to help me.
I am new to NestJS.

I want to be able to call the Steam login page (with:
"https://steamcommunity.com/openid/") and return the connection to me. I want to be able to put a token to indicate that the person is connected.

I find a lot of things in ExpressJS but I can't implement in NestJS.
It's been non-stop day that I try to find solutions but I can't find it at all.
If a charitable person could help me, it would take a huge weight off me.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you've tried and where you're stuck. You can use any passport strategy with NestJS and the `@nestjs/passport `package, or you could roll your own OAuth login flow.

Comment: I can't. I tried with "passport-steam", with "passport" , but I can't manage to set it up. I have this:
"https://github.com/XtReLL/csgo-opencase-backend/blob/main/auth/app.js" and other sources like this in express, but I can't seem to get it up and running.

Comment: I don't know how to correctly use "@nest/passport " and "Strategy".
Basically, the steam connection is done on the front on Flutter, but we changed technology to be on Ionic/Angular and there is a need to secure and put a "Bearer-Token" with "jwt" (reconnection to the app without asking for the steam connection again)
I really don't know how to go about it. I've been there since 7:30 this morning. I totally block.